# get the item from json fixture in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have json like that:

```
[
  {
    fields: {
      username: "andriy",
      first_name: "",
      last_name: "",
      is_active: true,
      is_superuser: true,
      is_staff: true,
      last_login: "2015-03-26T13:20:01.902Z",
      groups: [ ],
      user_permissions: [ ],
      password: "pbkdf2_sha256$12000$YluCbMyidWwL$yH",
      email: "",
      date_joined: "2015-03-26T13:19:23.269Z"
    },
    model: "auth.user",
    pk: 4
  },
```

and try to get value of item 'username':

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
from django.http import HttpResponse

path = 'management/test.json'
def load_fixture(name):
    r = json.load(open(path,'r+'), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
    dic =  json.dumps(r, indent=2)
    name = dic['fields'][0]['username'] 
    return HttpResponse(name)
```

or in such way:

```
....
    def load_fixture(name):
    with open(path,'r+') as json_file:
        json_data = json_file.read()
        dic = json.loads(json_data)
        name = dic['fields'][0]['username']

        return HttpResponse(name)
```

and always get errors:"string indices must be integers, not str" or "list indices must be integers, not str"(in second code). But why? It does dict, not string. I've read tons of similar topics here and there and seems make how people advice. What wrong with my code?!

Comment: `json.dumps` gives you a string, not a dict. Also, your `fields` key has `json` as value, and you're accessing it's `0th` index.

Comment: just tried: name = dic[0]['fields']['username'] and it returns"andriy" .Thats it but strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dic['fields'][0]['username']` should change to `dic[0]['fields']['username']`. So The second source code should be:

```
def load_fixture(name):
with open(path,'r+') as json_file:
    json_data = json_file.read()
    dic = json.loads(json_data)
    name = dic[0]['fields']['username']

    return HttpResponse(name)
```

Comment: Thank you! I have done like that an it works for me.